# Spring Boot - Read PDF from File server and Display on UI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-stream

I want to read the PDF from window file server and display on UI.

I have tried below code for reading from resource folder, however, i want to read from server and display.

```
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getDemoPDF() throws IOException {
        ClassPathResource pdf = new ClassPathResource("Test.pdf");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=Test.pdf");
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(pdf.contentLength())
                .body(new InputStreamResource(pdf.getInputStream()));
    }
```

Comment: This code will download the pdf to the client, your client's browser will show that if it has the right plugin.

Comment: Look at https://www.codejava.net/java-se/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example, to get file stream from a remote server, then hook in your existing logging to sent the response